# Strange error Assertion failed: (slab->magic == SLAB_MAGIC (bucket_idx))

Tags: xcode, ios5, gridview, assertion

I´m developing an app in `IOS-5` using the following sample code: [GridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView)

```
 Assertion failed: (slab->magic == SLAB_MAGIC (bucket_idx)), function slab_dealloc, file x-alloc.c, line 567.
```

I've changed the code and this error appears. What is this error about?

Comment: look at this :https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-dev/ISIn_RVFojg

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely memory corruption. I just had the same error and the reason was that I was calling `release` on something that I'd forgotten to `retain`.

Comment: this is correct +1 :) Just received this error and was related to a double release of memory.